# UE4: How to create a USceneComponent in C++ and move it in blueprint viewport

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

Inside my character cpp I want to define two USceneComponent variables and create them using CreateDefaultSubobject. What UPROPERTY or other things do I need to add to be able to move the scene components in the blueprint viewport that inherits from the c++ class?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to make a member variable and make it visible

```
UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere)
USceneComponent* SceneComponent;
```

You also can add `BlueprintReadOnly` or `BlueprintReadWrite` if you plan to access this component in the blueprint